# Missing words WordData

Tags: curated-data

I'm using WordData to check text, I want to omit placenames, non English words etc. I've noticed a few peculiar returns from this function for certain inputs, for example:

> `WordData["would"]`
>
> `WordData["could"]`

both return an empty list. I don't think this should happen

I'm connected to the internet and (I think) Mathematica downloads data from Wolfram when I run the above from a new kernel.

Comment: Same thing here. It doesn't really make any sense, since most words give information...

Comment: it seems that `WordData`  contains none of  _auxiliary verbs_